# Display categories used by author in author archive in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display all categories used only by a given author with Parent AND child display with hierarchy in author archive.

**Example :**

- A1 is child of A
- A2 is child of A
- The author posted 1 posts in A1
- The author posted 1 posts in A2
- The author posted 1 posts in C and A1 (same post)
- The author posted 1 post in B

**Result wanted :**

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=56">A</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=57">A1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=58">A2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=3">B</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=4">C</a></li>
<li><a href="http://example.com/?cat=5">D is not displayed because author didn't post in this category</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cat_array = array();
$args=array(
 'author' => get_the_author_meta('id'),
 'showposts'=>-1,
 'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$author_posts = get_posts($args);
if( $author_posts ) {
  foreach ($author_posts as $author_post ) {
    foreach(get_the_category($author_post->ID) as $category) {
      $cat_array[$category->term_id] =  $category->term_id;
    }
  }
}

$cat_ids = implode(',', $cat_array);
echo $output = strtr( wp_list_categories( 'include='.$cat_ids.'&title_li=&style=none&echo=0' ), array( '<br />' => ' / ' ) );
```